# (or/c #f <contract>) vs <contract>

Tags: racket, design-by-contract

According to the following example from the [struct/dc entry](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fstruct-dc..rkt%29._struct%2Fdc%29%29) in the Racket reference manual, the `bst/c` function below returns a contract such as every node in `bt` has its value bound between `lo` and `hi`.

```
(struct bt (val left right))

(define (bst/c lo hi)
  (or/c #f
        (struct/dc bt
                   [val (between/c lo hi)]
                   [left (val) #:lazy (bst lo val)]
                   [right (val) #:lazy (bst val hi)])))
```

That definition looks perfect to me, except for one thing: what is the purpose of the `(or/c #f [...])` construct here ?  Since `#f` is a constant that always evaluates to false, why not just remove the `or/c` logic altogether, and simply define `bst/c` as:

```
(define (bst/c lo hi)
  (struct/dc bt
             [val (between/c lo hi)]
             [left (val) #:lazy (bst lo val)]
             [right (val) #:lazy (bst val hi)]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary search tree with a single value is constructed as:

```
 (bst 42 #f #f)
```

Here #f is used to indicated that the left and right subtrees are empty.

Since we want the left and right subtrees also to be binary search trees, we need to include the value #f as a legal bst. The contract (or/c #f ...) says just that.

Comment: Ah, thank you for this explanation;  it makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Incidentally, you may also commonly see `(or/c #f <contract> ...+)` as a contract for the return value of functions that fail by returning `#f` (as opposed to failing by raising an exception, or using a `Maybe`-ish `struct`, or whatever). Another variant is to use `'some-symbol-indicating failure` instead of `#f`.